# QXmlStreamReader (Qt5): get all sub-elements inside a tag

Tags: c++, qt, xml-parsing, qt5

My XML to parse is something like this:

```
 <posts>
   <post>
     <id>1234</id>
     <file_url>/foo/bar</file_url>
   </post>
 </posts>
```

Now, I need to insert, for every children of `post`, its tag name and content in a QVariantMap, where the key is the tag, and the content (text) is the value.

Also, this is what a web API returns, so I *cannot* hardcode tag names (except from "post") as results may vary depending on what call is made.

My code:

```
QXmlStreamReader reader;
reader.addData(data); // data is a QByteArray obtained from the API call
while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
        qDebug() << reader.name();
        if (reader.name() == "post") {
            while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                qDebug() << reader.name() << reader.text();
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens however is that I only get "id" and nothing else. As far as I understand from the documentation, this is the expected behavior, which however isn't what I need.

What should I do to obtain only the tags between `<post>` and `</post>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using reader.text() you need to tell the XML reader to move to the next element by using reader.readElementText() or by using reader.skipCurrentElement() if the element isn't what you're looking for.

```
QXmlStreamReader reader;
reader.addData(data); // data is a QByteArray obtained from the API call
while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
    qDebug() << reader.name();
    if (reader.name() == "post") {
        while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                qDebug() << reader.name() << reader.readElementText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could, if need be, but I don't want to hardcode looking for tags, as I just quoted one example, which uses "post", but there are others, with different sub-tags. I need to do it "machine gun style", getting every possible tag between the start and end. EDIT: I also noticed that this stops at the first "id".

Comment: In that case, just do what you were doing but replace reader.text() with reader.readElementText() "edited above"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [QXmlStreamWriter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html#writeCurrentToken) class and the `writeCurrentToken` method to get the input XML. For example the following extracts until the closing `</post>` text:

```
QXmlStreamReader reader;
reader.addData(data);

QString outerXml;
QXmlStreamWriter writer(&outerXml);

while (!reader.isEndElement()
       || reader.name() != "post")
{
    writer.writeCurrentToken(mXmlReader);
    reader.readNext();
}
writer.writeCurrentToken(reader);
```

From the Qt docs:

> `void QXmlStreamWriter::writeCurrentToken(const QXmlStreamReader &reader)`
>
> Writes the current state of the reader. All possible valid
> states are supported.
>
> The purpose of this function is to support chained processing of XML
> data.